MSVC seems to wrongfully accept concept constraints
The following code fails to compile on MSVC, is the compiler exhibiting buggy behavior? I would expect the static assertion of not d<t> to pass since x is a private member of t and therefore inaccessible when attempting to access via T::x inside concept d.
namespace n { template<typename> using a = void; }

template<typename> concept c = true;
template<typename T> concept d = c<n::a<decltype(T::x)>>;

struct s { int x; };
class t : s {};

static_assert(d<s>);
static_assert(not d<t>); // clang ok, msvc nope

Demo

The code example in the linked to question only compiles with GCC, with the argument given that the normalization of the provided concept's constraint-expression only has an empty template parameter mapping, which can't result in substitution failure, thereby favoring the behavior of GCC.
However, the rules that apply to the normal form of a concept-id become irrelevant when replacing it with an expression, for example, with a templated variable of type bool. In this case, all compilers will evalute the concept as unsatisfied.
When applying that change to the example of this question, we observe that MSVC still deviates from the expected behavior. This makes it clear that there is a different root cause in effect between these two questions. Therefore, this question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate and should be re-opened. To ignore the edits I made previously, or to simply refuse to try to gain an understanding of the nuances involved here, isn't going to help anyone.

Is it ill-formed to attempt to access private member of a class to sfinae out overload? and Can SFINAE detect private access violations?

@user12002570 Note that this isn't just about accessibility, as placing alias a in the global namespace or simply commenting out the first static assertion, will make the code compile on MSVC.

Making one more compiler compile this program doesn't mean that it's not just about accessibility. The compilers may be buggy.
